# Want to update .Net Framework filters to .Net 6

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, .net-4.8

I want to upgrade the Filter.config file from .Net Framework to .Net 6.
I am facing an isse.
here is the code that I want to upgrade. How can I?

I tried and I field
the code is attached that i want to update.
can anybody help?

```
  public class RequireAuthHeader : ActionFilterAttribute
        {
            public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext filterContext)
            {
                string path = filterContext.Request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath.Replace("/api/", "");
                if (!filterContext.Request.RequestUri.ToString().Contains("localhost"))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        RequestHeader requestHeader = new RequestHeader();
                        requestHeader = RequestAuthorizer.Header(filterContext.Request, path);
                        if (requestHeader.Flag == false)
                        {
                            filterContext.Response = filterContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable);
                        }
                        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                        GenericRepository<Message> verify = new GenericRepository<Message>("API_VerifyBearer", path);
                        Task<Message> message = Task.Run(async () => await verify.ExecuteStoreProcedureSingleReturn(new
                        {
                            Bearer = requestHeader.Bearer,
                            userID = requestHeader.UserID
                        }));
                        if (message.Result?.Status == "200")
                        {
                            string verifyBearer = Security.ValidateToken(requestHeader.Bearer);
                            if (verifyBearer == null && requestHeader.UserID != 276835)
                            {
                                filterContext.Response = filterContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            filterContext.Response = filterContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        string innerExc = ex.InnerException != null ? ex.InnerException.ToString() : "";
                        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                        Log.APIError("RequireAuthHeader-Filter", path, ex.ToString() + "\n InnerException:" + innerExc, ex.StackTrace.ToString());
                        filterContext.Response = filterContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Action filters allow you to look at requests right before they are routed to an action method (and responses right after they are returned from the action method).

The simplest way to add your own action filter in ASP.NET Core is to subclass ActionFilterAttribute and then override the appropriate methods depending on if you want to look at the request, result, or both.

Here’s an example that overrides OnActionExecuting() so it can look at the request:

Comment: What is the exact problem? Are you having compiler errors?

Comment: You can't reuse ASP.NET filters in ASP.NET Core. The entire runtime *and* architecture has changed. .NET 6 is .NET *Core* 6, a completely different runtime. ASP.NET Core was rebuilt as well.

Comment: _" I am facing an isse [sic]."_ What _issue_ are you facing?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this filter?  You'll have to find the equivalent in ASP.NET Core 6. In fact, looking at the code I see some pretty big bugs like using the obsolete `JavaScriptSerializer` which can't even handle dates and database access *in the filter*.

Comment: `requestHeader.Bearer` are you trying to implement JWT authentication? That's already available. ASP.NET Core already supports JWT, OpenID and more. The way to use these is already described in the documentation. Authentication is the job of the Authentication middleware, not action filters. `builder.Services.AddAuthentication("Bearer").AddJwtBearer();` is enough to support JWT for example

Comment: Check [Overview of ASP.NET Core authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-7.0). Bearer tokens are so common they're used as an example in the Overview. The rest of the section shows how to use other authentication providers including OpenID, Google, Azure, how to create your own custom provider etc